# Commit and push changes to github repo from app hosted on github pages

Tags: javascript, git, github, github-api, github-pages

I need to add some uncommon functionality to my JavaScript app hosted on gh-pages in internal github copy of company I work in. So app code is on master branch and minified production build is deployed automatically to gh-pages.
App's logic is separate from model. Model stored in a json file. So I need to add functionality to my application to edit model then commit and push changes to json file to both master and gh-pages branches.

I know that there is jekyll on back-end, and github-api available. But I couldn't find how I can update file in repo from client side code, javascript.

So how do I do that?